# Why do these two files hash to the same value when I use MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, hash, memorystream, sha512

I'm writing a c# routine that creates hashes from jpg files.  If I pass in a byte array to my SHA512 object then I get the expected behavior, however, if I pass in a memory stream the two files always hash to the same value.

Example 1:

```
        SHA512 mySHA512 = SHA512.Create();

        Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"d:\img1.jpg");
        Image img2 = Image.FromFile(@"d:\img2.jpg");
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();

        img1.Save(ms1, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] buf1 = ms1.GetBuffer();
        byte[] hash1 = mySHA512.ComputeHash(buf1);

        img2.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] buf2 = ms2.GetBuffer();
        byte[] hash2 = mySHA512.ComputeHash(buf2);

        if (Convert.ToBase64String(hash1) == Convert.ToBase64String(hash2))
            MessageBox.Show("Hashed the same");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Different hashes");
```

That produces "Different hashes".  But one of the overloads of the ComputeHash method takes a stream object in and I'd rather use that.  When I do:

```
        SHA512 mySHA512 = SHA512.Create();

        Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"d:\img1.jpg");
        Image img2 = Image.FromFile(@"d:\img2.jpg");
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();

        img1.Save(ms1, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] hash1 = mySHA512.ComputeHash(ms1);

        img2.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] hash2 = mySHA512.ComputeHash(ms2);

        if (Convert.ToBase64String(hash1) == Convert.ToBase64String(hash2))
            MessageBox.Show("Hashed the same");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Different hashes");
```

That produces "Hashed the same".

What's going on here that I'm missing?

Comment: They're not copies of the _same_ image, are they?

Comment: What happens if you seek to the beginning of the stream after the .Save call?  e.g. ms1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: In this case you could use `mySHA512.ComputeHash.ComputeHash(ms1.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms1.Length)`. Avoids unnecessary copies

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I'll also point out that the `MemoryStream.GetBytes()` method would be more correct than calling `GetBuffer()`. The former restricts the data returned to the actual contents of the stream, while the latter returns the complete buffer, including unused padding at the end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're not rewinding your MemoryStreams, so the hash is computed from an empty sequence of bytes. Use

```
ms1.Position = 0;
ms2.Position = 0;
```

after calling `Save`.

One further note: don't use `GetBuffer` in this way. Use `ToArray` which will give you a byte array the same size as the stream's length - `GetBuffer` returns the raw buffer which will (usually) have some padding, which you wouldn't want to use accidentally. You can use `GetBuffer` if you then make sure you only use the relevant portion of it, of course - this avoids creating a new copy of the data.